# psychological database with sequenced DNA records

Tags: genetics, behaviour, epigenetics, psychology

I'm looking for an epigenetic database which includes for each example the psychological history of the persons DNA. Right now I can only find DNA and epigenetic databases. Sadly none of the databases provide "thick data" (qualitative data eg. history of person) to the sequenced DNA.

I want to investigate the effects of psychology on epigenetic and vice versa.

Comment: I would be very surprised if such a thing exists. Apart from the privacy issues (OK, you can anonymize the data), there aren't to my knowledge any projects for such large scale sequencing of human samples. The closest I can think of is the [1000 genomes project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1000_Genomes_Project) but I doubt any psychological data will be included.

Comment: [23andme](https://www.23andme.com/), for example,  along with SNP data collects information on different traits (including behavioral) from their customers and publishes interesting results from time to time, but their database is not for public usage.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the Danish Data archive:

http://www.sa.dk/content/us/about_us/danish_data_archive

I have never used their data and I don't know what barriers there might be to accessing it, but the impression I got at a talk by Soren Brunak (http://ctbr.hunter.cuny.edu/Brunak), was that this was one of the most complete databases for studying relationships between people's DNA records and other health information that might be available about them.